# Deno types show type /*unresolved*/ any

Tags: typescript, deno

Deno types show `/*unresolved*/ any` – I get no type information

Example

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';

const stripe = Stripe(stripeApiKey);

    const paymentIntent: Stripe.PaymentIntent =
      await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: 1000,
      });
```

Comment: Can you show how you create your `stripe` instance?

Comment: `const stripe = Stripe(stripeApiKey);`

Comment: I don't know if this counts as an answer, but I do have a few debug suggestions
1. Make sure you definitely have types imported. Install types using this command:`deno install --unstable --importmap=import_map.json --root=./types https://deno.land/x/typescript@<version>/typescript.js
`
2. check if you have a tsconfig.json file to configure your typescript. Make sure:
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  }
}`
those two modules are set to true
3. And finally check that deno has sufficient permissions on your device

Comment: Could you clarify in your code example where the type is `any`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the types were half-way working, but not fully, because

```
const stripe = new Stripe(stripeApiKey);
```

was missing `new`.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on where you are importing from. Using ems.sh it needs a slight adjustment for the types to be happy. Using `npm:stripe` seems to work fine:

```js
// import Stripe from "npm:stripe";
import {Stripe} from "https://esm.sh/stripe@14.7.0";

const stripe = new Stripe("sk_test_...");

const paymentIntent: Stripe.PaymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: 1000,
  currency: "usd",
});

console.log(paymentIntent);
```

Tested with deno 1.38.4